# How do you define the continuity of real functions over Natural numbers?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Consider a well known function $ f(x) = x$,  we all know that the function is continue over $ \Bbb R $ but how about if define it over $\Bbb Z$ or $\Bbb N$ ? Clearly we can't use the same approach to calculate the limit because values are not included in $\Bbb N$. So is it now a discontinue function?

Comment: This is most easily done in the language of a subject called point-set topology, which you probably haven't encountered yet. In that language, the natural numbers have the discrete topology, which means that every function out of them is continuous!

Comment: characteristic for continuous is $x_n\to x\implies f(x_n)\to f(x)$. If $x_n\to x$ in $\mathbb N$ or $\mathbb Z$ then $x_n=x$ for $n$ large enough, so then also $f(x_n)=f(x)$ and consequently indeed $f(x_n)\to f(x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual topology of $\Bbb Z$ or $\Bbb N$ is discrete, so continuity becomes trivial.

A function from $S$ to $T$ is continuous if the preimage of an open set in $T$ is open in $S$. When $S=\Bbb N$, every set is open in $S$ because the topology is discrete, so every function is continuous.

Comment: That is, **every** function $f \colon \mathbb Z \to \mathbb R$ is considered "continuous".

Comment: @GEdgar Yes, indeed

Comment: But i have function that is a product of a continue function and a function that accept only discreet values,  a good example is a function of two variable x, and y , x, x geometric distributed hence y is beta distributed, to find the marginal function of y i need too integrate over f  with respect to x so the results is a function only dependent on y but as my reference says that is the 'not continue' function. Am i confusing different things here?